# Permission assignment to allow a user to just execute a pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Getting below error while executing the pipeline from the user
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7ZZl.png)

Comment: Hi, if my reply is helpful, please consider [accepting it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), it can help other community members, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

To fix the issue, try to follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the `Project Settings` of the specific project -> select a group e.g. `Contributors` -> `Members` -> `Add` -> add the user account.

[image]

2.In the pipeline, check which repo the pipeline is getting source from.

[image]

3.In the `Project Settings` -> select the repo in step 2.

[image]

Make sure the `Read` permission of the selected group in step 1(in my sample is `Contributors`) is `Allow` and `Disable Repository` is `Off`.

[image]

[image]

Then try to run the pipeline again, it should work.

[image]